# How can l fix the object transparency issue?

Tags: physics

[image]

Hi, the picture in the circle is that the sink drain. l applied fluid physics and the domain property to the object and it became transparent. How can l fix the object transparency issue?

Comment: You don't want to make the object the domain.  You need to create a separate cube surrounding the object and make that the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, Zisan.  The object you select and apply Quick Fluid to will become a Flow "Geometry Container" (like an initial pool of water), which is not renderable so it looks as such.  If you want BOTH the drain as a visual object AND want it to also the be part of the Physics (my guess is an Outflow?), then what you should do to correct this is :

1. Duplicate the drain object
2. On one of the two drain objects, remove the fluid modifier
3. Be sure your other drain object has Fluid set to Outflow, not Geometry.

You may find other issues if the geometry of the Outflow is insufficient.   In fact -- for accuracy -- you may really want a set of cylinders that align with the drain Holes to be your Fluid Outflow.
[image]

For Quick Effects, Liquid I would use the following workflow:

1. Draw the Visual objects for your fluids Container (Tub), Drain, Faucet
2. the Physics objects including initial (frame 1) volume of fluid (e.g. partially filled tub), outflow (drain), and inflow (inside the Faucet)
3. Select all of these objects and do a Quick Effects, Liquid
4. Leave the Physics on the initial liquid alone, but visit all other objects and change them to Effector (Visual Objects from #1) or to Inflow or Outflow

I leave you an example: [image]

Comment: Thanks for your helping me the issue fixed.